# Error using DBunit to export a DB "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dbunit/database/IDatabaseConnection"

Tags: java, jdbc, export, dbunit, jtds

I've got the following java code, which is giving the error below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet;

public class export {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // database connection
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/exampleDB", "sa", "vista1");
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

        // full database export
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));
    }
}
```

**Error:**

$ java export

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dbunit/database/IDatabaseConnection
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: export.  Program will exit.
```

The name of the java file being compiled is `export.java` and the name of the compiled file is `export.class`, and I've put the `dbunit-2.4.8.jar` and `jtds-1.2.5.jar` files in to the same folder as `export.java` and `export.class`; and I'm compiling export.java with the following cmd:

```
$ javac -cp "dbunit-2.4.8.jar;jtds-1.2.5.jar" export.java
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The goal is to export a simple mssql DB to a flat xml file using dbunit.

Comment: Also tried `DriverManager.registerDriver(new net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver());` instead of `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");` as I see used in other examples, but that does not change the error produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this on an oracle database and it works fine ^^

```
IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection, "SCHEMA_OF_YOUR_DB");
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, but using maven (m2eclipse) and running it from inside Eclipse. My problem was fixed when I removed the scope=test from the dbunit dependency.

I also tried to run from console, using javac and java, like you did, but got the same error. It must have been because of some dependencies we forgot to include on the classpath. We need only dbunit.jar to compile, but dbunit classes depend on other things to actually run, so we need to put other jars on the classpath when running (slf4j, for example).

When running successfully from inside Eclispe, here are my dependecies:
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar (using oracle)
dbunit-2.4.8.jar
junit-3.8.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

Try to put them all on the classpath and see if it works.

About the error message.. Despite the fact that it says 'Could not find the main class: export.  Program will exit.', it's not really true. It does find the main class, and I could debug the execution after I commented out all lines after the second. The problem hapens only if I import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection. I believe that, when this class is imported, the main class tries to load DatabaseConnection, which tries to load something that is not in the classpath. So the java gives a misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace ends with

> "Could not find the main class: export. Program will exit."

This tells me that 'export' is not in your classpath at execution time. Your classpath must include 'export.class'. Just because it is in the same folder as the JARs does not mean it is automatically in the classpath.

Comment: just tried `javac -cp "dbunit-2.4.8.jar;jtds-1.2.5.jar;export.class" export.java` then `java -cp "dbunit-2.4.8.jar;jtds-1.2.5.jar;export.class" export` and that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the -cp parameter when you run the `java` commandline. Like so:

`java -cp "dbunit-2.4.8.jar;jtds-1.2.5.jar" export`

Comment: just tried `javac -cp "dbunit-2.4.8.jar;jtds-1.2.5.jar;export.class" export.java` then `java -cp "dbunit-2.4.8.jar;jtds-1.2.5.jar;export.class" export` and that didn't make a difference.